# How keep the debug layout the same as the desktop layout

Tags: delphi, ide

I try to have a similar layout during editing as well debugging. When running the program my structure and object inspector disappear. I did create my own desktop speedsetting, set the debug desktop to it as well, but as soon as the program runs structure and obejct inspector disappear. How can I prevent that?

A question related to this: the edit menu changes as well. A right click on a procedure name results in a popup menu with the first item being "find declaration". When debugging the first item is "close page". I find the find declaration item a fast way to find some code. Apart from that it is frustrating to lose one's code because you click "no" on the question to save the information (I know, it's my fault but menu's shouldn't change in my opinion).

Thanks,

Arnold

Comment: The menu changes because the context changes. The debug desktop setting that you describe solves your first problem. You must be doing it not quite right.

Comment: Object inspector possibly disappears as a result of "hide designers at runtime" option...

Comment: @Arnold Good morning .. I think your doubt can be taken here ..:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Saving_Desktop_Layouts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Delphi? Dialogs and menus change between versions (and even between SKUs of the same version).

For the first, open `Tools->Options->Environment Options` and uncheck `Hide designers on run` in the `Running` group box (D2010, XE, and XE2), or `Tools->Options->Environment Options` and unchecking `Hide designers on run` in the `Compiling and Running` group box (D2007).

For the second: The right-click menu is called a `context menu`, meaning it displays what is appropriate in the context of when it's being shown. It's entirely appropriate for it to change  depending on when and how you're using it; that's the way it's supposed to work.

Right-clicking on a `.zip` file in Windows Explorer is different than right-clicking on a Word `.doc` file, because they have different options based on *context* - a zip file has an 'Extract to...' option that the Word document doesn't have, because 'extracting' a Word document doesn't apply. Same applies to right-clicking a `.exe` file, which has the `Run as Administrator` option (Win7), as opposed to right-clicking a `.pas` file, which doesn't offer that option.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. And an excellent illustration of an answer that expands well on hurriedly written comments.

Comment: @David, thanks. The comments weren't there when I started writing my answer, I swear. :) I got a phone call in the middle of writing my post. Point taken, though. <g>

Comment: I am using Delphi XE. This answer perfectly works ok, thanks! Pity of the context menu.